# Contact Form PHP Include

Tags: forms

I'm not sure how to ask my question, but I have a contact form that is include on every page of my website: http://assistedlivingbridgeton.com/ (the "schedule your tour" form).

Currently, this is the form processing code:

```
    <?php
     // if the url field is empty 
     if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){
 // then send the form to your email
    $email = "knunn@standrews1.com, eechols@standrews1.com";
     $message = "The following information was submitted from the Schedule Your Tour form on your website:\n
     ";
     $message .= "Name: ".$_REQUEST["Name__1"]."\n\n";
     $message .= "Email: ".$_REQUEST["Email__2"]."\n\n";
     $message .= "Phone: ".$_REQUEST["Phone__3"]."\n\n";
     $message .= "Best date/time: ".$_REQUEST["Best_datetime__4"]."\n\n";
     mail( $email, "Bridgeton Assisted Living Tour Form", $message, "From: $email
     X-Priority: 1 (Highest)" );
     header("Location: http://www.assistedlivingbridgeton.com/thanks.php");
     } 
     // otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
     ?>
     <h1>Thanks</h1>
     We'll get back to you as soon as possible
     ?>
```

What I would like to do is have one form processing script that pops in a "thank you" message kinda like a php include where that Tour Form is on the sidebar.  The way I have it set up now, I have to have a process script and a thankyou page for each landing page on my site that has that form.  I want one script, that will pop in the thank you message to whatever page the form was filled out from.  Does that make sense?  Help please!  I know its possible because if you use Foxy Form or something similar, that's exactly what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<iframe>` to do that.
You create a file : form.php, write all your code including the thank you and the form itself and then just call this page where ever you want using iframe. Thus you add this code to all pages where you want the form to appear and the result thank you will appear in the same page:

```
<iframe src="form.php" width="150px" height="250px" border="0">
```

more information about iframe you can get here: [w3schools iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)